# spring boot junit mock is not returning expected value

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I think it's logically correct. I mocked the classes then I wrote when-then expression but when I want to assertEquals(expected,actual) it's returning ***org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError***

ShortUrlServiceTest:

```
private ShortUrlRepository shortUrlRepository;
    private UserService userService;
    private RandomStringGenerator randomStringGenerator;
    private ShortUrlService shortUrlService;
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        shortUrlRepository = mock(ShortUrlRepository.class);
        userService = mock(UserService.class);
        randomStringGenerator = mock(RandomStringGenerator.class);
        shortUrlService = new ShortUrlService(shortUrlRepository, userService, randomStringGenerator);
    }
    @Test
    public void testCreateWhenCodeDoesNotExistThenSave() {
        final var expected = generateShortUrl();
        when(shortUrlRepository.findByCode(expected.getCode()))
                .thenReturn(Optional.empty());
        when(userService.getUserById(expected.getUser().getId()))
                .thenReturn(expected.getUser());
        when(shortUrlRepository.save(expected))
                .thenReturn(expected);
        final var actual = shortUrlService.create(
                generateCreateShortUrlRequest(expected.getUrl(),
                        expected.getCode()),
                expected.getUser().getId()
        );
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
```

ShortUrlService:

```
@Service @RequiredArgsConstructor @Slf4j
public class ShortUrlService {
    private final ShortUrlRepository repository;
    private final UserService userService;
    private final RandomStringGenerator randomStringGenerator;
    public ShortUrl create(CreateShortUrlRequest createShortUrlRequest, Long id) {
        String code = createShortUrlRequest.getCode();
        log.info("Code: " + code);

        if (code == null || code.isEmpty()) {
            code = generateCode();
            log.info("Code generated automatically: " + code);
        } else if (repository.findByCode(code).isPresent()) {
            throw new CodeAlreadyExistsException(ExceptionMessages.SHORT_URL_ALREADY_EXISTS.getValue());
        }
        log.info("Code not found in db,it's okay: " + code); // it is working

        ShortUrl shortUrl = ShortUrl.builder()
                .url(createShortUrlRequest.getUrl())
                .user(userService.getUserById(id))
                .code(code)
                .build();

        log.info("ShortUrl created: " + shortUrl); // it is working
        return repository.save(shortUrl);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: you forget to turn those fields into mocks, and you forget to tell your class to use mocksµ

Comment: @ Mock and @ InjectMocks annotations are not working for me. Additionally, my other test methods are working. @Stultuske

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the mock for the shortUrl save method, your expected `ShortUrl` variable inside the mock call is not the same object to the one constructed and passed to the save method in the code being tested.

```
when(shortUrlRepository.save(expected)).thenReturn(expected);
```

Internally Mockito uses the `equal()` method to determine if the objects passed to a mock matchers the argument from the `when()` expression. If your class does not implement an `equals(`) method the default one from `Object.class` is used. And this means that only the same exact same object would match, from the [Java doumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html):

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating
> possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null
> reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x
> and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

You either need to change this to:

```
when(shortUrlRepository.save(any())).thenReturn(expected);
```

Or make sure that the `ShortUrl` class has an properly implemented `equals()` method, that instead of comparing object memory references instead check if all properties match.

Comment: Thank you so much it works! But I couldn't fully understand. Why it didn't work before? Because given object and returning object are not relational (other than same class) . How can I search the details (keywords, etc..)?

Comment: I edited my answer and elaborated the explanation.